# C# Antlr4 Maximize Speed

Tags: c#, antlr4

In Java there is this line `parser.getInterpreter().setSLL(true);` to switch the ANTLR4 parser to SLL(*). What is the equivalent in C#?

Thank you in advance, Widi

Comment: `parser.getInterpreter()` will be `parser.Interpreter` in C#, but there seems to be no `SLL` property...

Comment: Thats why I am asking :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't find any reference to setSLL. The wiki page [here](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/faq/general.md#why-is-my-expression-parser-slow) is using the setPredictionMode method to enable sll. Here is the java code snippet from the page.

```
CharStream input = new ANTLRFileStream(args[0]);
ExprLexer lexer = new ExprLexer(input);
CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
ExprParser parser = new ExprParser(tokens);
parser.getInterpreter().setPredictionMode(PredictionMode.SLL);
try {
    parser.stat();  // STAGE 1
}
catch (Exception ex) {
    tokens.reset(); // rewind input stream
    parser.reset();
    parser.getInterpreter().setPredictionMode(PredictionMode.LL);
    parser.stat();  // STAGE 2
    // if we parse ok, it's LL not SLL
}
```

Here is how you set the prediction mode in C#.

```
parser.Interpreter.PredictionMode = Antlr4.Runtime.Atn.PredictionMode.Sll;
```